# Efficient Timeout for a blocking operation without synchronization

Tags: java, io, thread-safety, thread-synchronization

I'm trying to create a timeout for a blocking operation, a `InputStream.read()` in the specific case, using a timeout thread **without** synchronization.

This is needed to avoid that a blocking operation will last forever and **its aim is to achieve the best performance**.

This should be a typical use case:

```
try(InputStream input = request.getInputStream())
{
    Utils.consumeWithTimeout(input, 60000, (buffer, n) ->
    {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        checksum.update(buffer, 0, n);
    });
}
```

where

```
public static void consumeWithTimeout(InputStream in, long timeout, BiConsumer<byte[], Integer> consumer) throws IOException
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];

    try(TimedOp timedOp = new TimedOp(timeout, () -> closeQuietly(in)))
    {
        while(true)
        {
            timedOp.start();
            int n = in.read(buf);
            timedOp.pause();

            if(n <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            consumer.accept(buf, n);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        closeQuietly(in);
    }
}
```

and

```
public static class TimedOp implements AutoCloseable
{
    private Thread th;
    private volatile long last = 0;
    private volatile boolean paused = true;

    public TimedOp(long timeout, Runnable runnable)
    {
        th = new Thread(() ->
        {
            try
            {
                while(!th.isInterrupted())
                {
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if(last + timeout > now)
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(last + timeout - now);
                    }
                    else if(paused)
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(timeout);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        runnable.run();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                return;
            }
        });
    }

    public void start()
    {
        State state = th.getState();
        if(state == State.TERMINATED)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("thread is terminated");
        }

        if(!paused)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("already running");
        }

        last = System.currentTimeMillis();
        paused = false;

        if(state == State.NEW)
        {
            th.start();
        }
    }

    public void pause()
    {
        paused = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
    {
        th.interrupt();
        try
        {
            th.join();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

do you see a problem or space for improvement?

---

### what I tried

Suppose you need to care about 1GB data transfer, with a 8KB buffer.

**can I use an `ExecutorService` for scheduling the `read()`?**

No, I can't.

```
public static void consumeWithExecutor(InputStream in, long timeout, BiConsumer<byte[], Integer> consumer) throws IOException
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(() -> in.read(buf));
            int n = future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if(n <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            consumer.accept(buf, n);
        }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e)
    {
        // do nothing, handling in finally block
    }
    finally
    {
        closeQuietly(in);
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

the overhead of spawning/reusing/restarting a thread for each single read is overkill.

Performance loss is unbearable.

**can I use a `Timer` for scheduling the `read()`?**

No, I shouldn't.

```
public static void consumeWithTimer(InputStream in, long timeout, BiConsumer<byte[], Integer> consumer) throws IOException
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];

    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer();

            TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    closeQuietly(in);
                }
            };

            timer.schedule(task, timeout);

            int n = in.read(buf);

            timer.cancel();

            if(n <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            consumer.accept(buf, n);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        closeQuietly(in);
    }
}
```

`Timer` and `TimerTask` are not reusable, a new instance should be created for each iteration.

Internally, `Timer` synchronizes on a `queue` of tasks, leading to unnecessary locking.

This result in a performance loss, a little thinner than using an `ExecutorService`, nevertheless it's not as efficient as my original implementation.

Comment: You seem to be in a Servlet, in which case you can configure a request timeout directly in the container.

Comment: You are right, I'm under Wildfly 10. Nevertheless I can't configure a general `read-timeout` because I need this specific `Servlet` to act with a longer timeout: it will be used for file upload over unstable networks (I'm implementing TUS protocol)